# How to follow a call into a dll with gdb?

Tags: gdb

I'm sure that the program I'm debugging has debug info, and I'm pretty sure that dlls I'm trying to get into are also compiled with the debug info. Yet I can't follow a dll call.

Tools are gdb, gcc, msys2, codeblocks, windows 7.

How to get the list of loaded dll? I need to check the paths at least.

The exe is suspiciously big, 500 KB, almost makes me think that libraries are linked statically instead of dinamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure that dlls I'm trying to get into are also compiled
>   with the debug info

Use `info sharedlibrary` to verify that debug info was loaded. For example in the following output all shared libraries are missing debugging information.
(Note the last line: `(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.`)

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary 
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7dd5d50  0x00007ffff7df4e20  Yes (*)     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007ffff7adb100  0x00007ffff7b8b7f8  Yes (*)     /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
0x00007ffff7701880  0x00007ffff77aa985  Yes (*)     /lib64/libm.so.6
0x00007ffff74e5ac0  0x00007ffff74f5de5  Yes (*)     /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
0x00007ffff7120770  0x00007ffff728d0fc  Yes (*)     /lib64/libc.so.6
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```